# After pivoting, collapsing new rows by common column values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have a data set containing 9 lab tests conducted for several patients(USUBJID), where each lab (LABCAT) had its own row and its respective day performed (LBDY). I want to transpose this so each lab is its own column and day performed is the value.

[image]

I performed a pivot as follows.

```
library(dplyr)
LB <- lb %>%
   select(USUBJID, LBCAT, LBDY)  %>%
   group_by(USUBJID) %>%
   mutate(visitnum = sequence(n())) %>%
   spread(key= LBCAT, value= LBDY)
```

This worked fine but now I want to merge the rows as a lot of these labs were conducted on the same days. So I want one row for all the labs conducted on day -21, one row for day -15, -2, etc. Is there an easy way to perform this task as I run into it occasionally and would like a long term solution.

[image]

Id like to the data to look like this

```
       Chemistry   Hematology Immunology   InfectiousDiseases Morphology ...
90301    -21          -21        NA           -21               -21
90301     NA          -15        NA            NA               -15
90301    -2           -2        -2             NA               -2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what you want the final output to look like?

Comment: Hi, Just added an end goal

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost does that, just group by `USUBJID` and `LBCAT`.

```
LB <- lb %>%
   select(USUBJID, LBCAT, LBDY)  %>%
   group_by(USUBJID, LBCAT) %>%
   mutate(visitnum = sequence(n())) %>%
   spread(key= LBCAT, value= LBDY)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Can you explain why grouping by the lab category has that effect when pivoting? What is exactly happening in the data?